# Not see remote changes after 'git pull --rebase'

Tags: git

I am trying to do a 'git pull --rebase', but I don't see any remote changes. 
When I do a 'git status' I see ' Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 12 commits.'

But I am current on my 'dev' branch, not master.

```
$ git branch
  master
* dev
```

And my 'dev' branch should track 'remotes/origin/dev'.

All I want is I am working on 'dev' and I want to get remote changes on remote dev.

But I did 'git pull --rebase' which some how pull remote 'master' changes to my 'dev' branch.

Can you pleases tell me how can I recover from my situation?

1. remove the changes I pull in from remote 'master' branch mistakenly (after i did 'git pull --rebase')
2. pull in the changes on remote 'dev' branch on to my 'dev' branch.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as if your dev branch was originally based on `origin/master` instead of `origin/dev`, or somehow `dev` has been changed to track `origin/master` anyway.  You can check this with:

```
git config branch.dev.merge
```

If that says `refs/heads/master` instead of `refs/heads/dev` you can change the upstream branch for your `dev` branch with:

```
git checkout dev
git branch --set-upstream dev origin/dev
```

Then, to fix your branch, I would:

1. Make sure that you're on the `dev` branch with `git checkout dev`
2. Make sure that `git status` is clean
3. Create a branch to save where you were (for safety): `git branch dev-wrongly-rebased`
4. Use `git reflog` to find the commit before you rebased onto `origin/master`
5. Reset `dev` to that point `git reset --hard COMMIT-BEFORE-BAD-REBASE`
6. Finally, do `git rebase origin/dev`

My preference when rebasing is always to do it in two steps, e.g.:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/dev
```

... since I think that's less error-prone than `git pull --rebase`.  I hope that's of some use.

Comment: Ok. I have tried' git branch --set-upstream origin/dev', but it said error: unknown option `set-upstream'. I am using git 1.6.3.3

Comment: Ah, OK.  It would be worth upgrading, since 1.6.3 is from June 2009 and there are lots of nice new features in git now.  However, you should be able to get the same effect with `git config branch.dev.merge refs/heads/dev`

Comment: (I assume that the previous value of `branch.dev.merge` was as I had guessed?)

Comment: Thanks. In 'git config branch.dev.merge refs/heads/dev', I should use 'refs/heads/dev'? not 'refs/origin/dev'? like u put in 'git branch --set-upstream' command? When I do 'git branch -r' I see origin/dev, not heads/dev.

Comment: @michael: Yes, it's confusing, I'm afraid, but `refs/heads/dev` is right.  It's the name of the ref from the point of view of the remote repository, not the local one.

Comment: I did the step up to #5 ' git reset --hard COMMIT-BEFORE-BAD-REBASE' but now when I do 'git status', it said 'Your branch is behind 'origin/dev' by 7 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.' Is that normal? I should proceed to step #6? Thank you again.

Comment: I assume you mean "up to and including #5"?  If so, that sounds as if before you did the bad rebase, you hadn't done any commits on `dev` which had diverged from what's on the remote `dev`.  If that's correct, then you're fine and can just do `git merge origin/dev`.  If that doesn't sound right, then I'd guess that you've reset back to the wrong commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the commits on top of the correct remote branch with

```
git rebase --preserve-merges --onto origin/dev start end
```

for a range of commits specified by start and end to be moved onto dev.

Then, set up tracking properly. If you want, you can edit the .git/config file and compare how traking is set up for each branch all at once and ensure consistent behavior.

From now on, of you are getting a new remote branch

```
git checkout -t origin/branch_name
```

Or if you are pushing a new branch to the remote

```
git push -u origin branch_name
```

These will set up traking as you want.

Hope this helps.